# Update choice field SchemaXml using powershell

Tags: powershell, xml, schema

I want to change the choice field from drop down to MultiChoice. 
How to Update choice field SchemaXml using powershell. Also how to get SchemaXml property.
[image]

Comment: Are you simply trying to change the Choice field from Drop-Down to Checkboxes via PowerShell? Otherwise, what are you trying to do via SchemaXml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume what you are trying to do is change a Choice field's type using PowerShell.  In that case you can do something like this:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://your.site.url.here
$list = $web.Lists["YourList"]
$field = $list.Fields["YourField"]
$field.Type = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::MultiChoice
$field.Update()
```

The SharePoint SPFieldType Enumeration information is here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldtype.aspx